# The property's value « $ » is null or not define, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm sorry for my English. I'm actually working on a website. My client is using IE11, and i use jQuery 3.1.0. You can see how i've implemented it:
(html code)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
<meta name="author" content="NAME">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Design" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>     
<div id = "boite_titre"> 
       <div id = "logo"><img src="images/img.gif"></div>
       <div id = "titre"><h1>TITLE</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="boite_menu"> 
    <UL id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">ODF</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo "Données du : ".$date_maj; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mise à jour données</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consultation ODF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chainages assemblées</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ajout equipement</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Renommage ODF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Changement ODF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Documentation sites</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">DERBI(IP)</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo "Données du : ".$date_maj; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mise à jour données</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Occupation d'un routeur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Recherche par la référence</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">OFFNET</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo "Données du : ".$date_maj; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mise à jour données</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tableau de suivi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consultation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CIRCULATOR</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo "Données du : ".$date_maj; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mise à jour données</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consultation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </UL>

</div>
<div id="boite_resultat"> 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pcjavascripts.js" ></script>
  <script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to do a sticky navigation with that jQuery wish is working correctly on last Firefox and Chrome but doesn't on IE11 with that error message on the IE11 debug: "The property's value « $ » is null or not define, not a Function object" (js code):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 350){  
        $('#boite_menu').css("position","fixed");
        $('#boite_menu').css("border-top","inset");
        $('#boite_menu').css("top","0");
    }
    else{
        $('#boite_menu').css("position","absolute");
        $('#boite_menu').css("top","10%");
        $('#boite_menu').css("border-top","none");
    }
});
```

css code:

```
#boite_menu
 {
 display: inline-block;
 z-index : 2;
 font-family : "Arial";
 font-size : 13;
 position:absolute;
 top:10%;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 border-right:inset ;
 border-left:inset ;
 border-bottom:inset ; 
 background-color:#F0F0F0;
 transition: all 0.40s ease-out;
 }
```

I've already read lot of similary cases but i didn't fixed my problems with these answers. Thanks you.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your window func inside a document on ready?

Comment: @JDE window is available before the document is ready, so no need to wrap it here

Comment: What if for testing purpose you switch to older jq version (e.g jq2.x)? What about browser cache?

Comment: window is ready but jQuery might not be ready.

Comment: @JDE in this case (jQuery not loaded), the document ready wrapper wouldn't work either

Comment: What. You are loading jquery. Are you sure jQuery is loaded before that function is ran?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118332/discussion-between-jd-e-and-a-wolff).

Comment: Thanks for your anwsers. @A.Wolff So Yes i tried with an older jQ like 2.x, same result : working on firefox but not on IE.

Comment: @JD E yes i did in that order.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pcjavascripts.js" ></script>

Comment: I have news! So i found something... I'm using IE11 but it's running with Entreprise wich emulate IE8